# Inductors in series with different currents

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, current-measurement, series, transient

[image]

I'm having trouble finding the differential equation that describes the circuit, at t=0 10A flow through L1 and 0A through L2, since current can't change instantaneously. But they're in series so they should have the same current. It seems like I can't find the differential equation using i(t) like I normally would in a series circuit because I don't have a value for i(0). So, how do you solve this?

And thinking about it, the same could happen with capacitors in parallel, how would I solve that as well?

This is from Linear Circuits - Ronald E. Scott.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the dual of a problem that has been discussed here on CO about paralleling a charged and an uncharged capacitor. Try to find that question for an in-depth explanation (and remember that you must swap the non-zero series resistor in that explanation for a non-infinite parallel resistor in your problem).

For you inductor question:

- with ideal components you problem is unsolvable, because (as you noticed) there are two conflicting requirements for the current at t=0: 10A and 0A.
- if you try this in real life the voltage across the switch will rise to the level that is required to let the 10A flow unimpeded. This will likely involve some interesting effects. This is a reason that switching high currents is difficult and not friendly to a switch.

Answer (score 4):

One approach, to gain some insight, would be to place a resistor \$R\$ in parallel with the the 2H inductor, write the differential equation, solve and take the limit as the resistance \$R \rightarrow \infty \$.

This will allow you to avoid the discontinuity at \$t=0\$ (for finite \$R\$) and see what happens to the voltages and currents as the limit is taken.

You'll find that, when the switch opens, the inductor voltages are

$$v_{3H}(0+) = 3A \cdot (R + 5\Omega)$$

$$v_{2H}(0+) =3A \cdot R$$

Clearly, as \$R \rightarrow \infty\$, these voltages go to infinity so, for the circuit as drawn, there will be a voltage impulse when the switch opens that results in a discontinuous inductor current.

But, of course, this solution is of 'academic' interest only since it is *highly* non-physical.